# Join one to many and get average of many divided by one?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables

```
companies
id
value

companies_products
company_id
order_count
```

and I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT
  (AVG(companies_products.order_count) / companies.value) as special_number
FROM companies
JOIN on companies_products on companies_products.company_id = companies.id
```

Is that going to correctly divide the averages for `companies_products.order_count` by that `company_id`'s `value` or is aggregating the companies `value`/picking a random company `value` to divide all the averages by?

Just to clarify. I do not want performance per company. I want the overall average of each company's average `order_count` / that companies `value` as one big average.

My problem is not that this query does not run, I'm just concerned that this is not acheiving what I'm looking for and short of creating some new tables I'm not sure how to prove whether it works or not. I get a number I'm just not sure its the **right** number

```
Sample Data:

companies data:

id: 1
value: 10

id: 2
value: 20

companies_products
company_id: 1
order_count: 20

company_id: 1
order_count: 40

company_id: 2
order_count: 20

company_id: 2
order_count: 20
```

Output

```
Result:
special_number: 2

Explanation:
avg of first company would be 3
avg of second company would be 1
```

*I'd love to know why I'm being downvoted.*

Comment: You don't have a join condition... are you trying for a cross product here, or are you missing part of your query?

Comment: Your query makes no sense, because it is an aggregation query that returns one row and `companies.value` is not summarized.  Sample data and desired results would really help communicate what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per company (as your comment seems to imply), then you need `group by`:

```
select c.id, avg(cp.order_count) / c.value) as special_number
from companies c join
     companies_products cp
     on cp.company_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.value;  -- the "c.value" is technically redundant, but I think it adds clarity
```

Comment: My apologies, I've clarified that I'm looking for one average which is the average of each companies `special_number`. Would the best way to achieve this be the query above as a subquery then averaged?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select (SELECT AVG(companies_products.order_count)  FROM companies
JOIN on companies_products on companies_products.company_id = companies.id)/ cast(companies.value as float)
FROM companies
JOIN on companies_products on companies_products.company_id = companies.id
```